# Disable autocomplete for html inputs

Tags: android, html, firefox, firefox-android

I'm searching for a way to make mobile browsers accept text input *as is* rather than fixing it automatically with features like [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) or [autocapitalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize). I.e. I want to get "wrong" inputs to identify spelling mistakes and typos manually.

For Chrome 87 on Android the following markup [from David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/disable-autocorrect) does exactly that:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false">
</form>
```

(As far as I can see [autocorrect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#autocorrect_This_API_has_not_been_standardized) and [spellcheck](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#spellcheck) are not even needed by Chrome, though.)

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for Firefox 84 on Android. E.g. when I type in `english`  character-by-character this will automatically be replaced with `English` . (I already discovered that the exact replacements depend on the used keyboard language. So for reference I'm using the Samsung keyboard with English (US) language here.) You can test yourself with different browsers [here](https://jsbin.com/zebitunoxa/1/edit?output).

So my question is: Is there a way to make Firefox - and ideally other mobile browsers - accept text input *as is* like Chrome does with the markup above?